# Where is the syntax error in my SQL Statement which uses an Outer Apply and Left Joins?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to find the syntax error in my SQL Server query which uses both `LEFT JOIN` and `OUTER APPLY`.  The purpose of the statement is to get the next `onhire` date of a vessel and show it in the result.

I'm not sure if I can switch on more detailed error messages but I simply get the following

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27 Incorrect syntax near 'Charterer'.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT
    po.[Id] AS [PositionId],
    ve.[Id] AS [VesselId],
    ve.[Name],
    fix1.[Date],
    fix1.[FirmUntil],
    ch1.[ChartererName] AS CurrentCharterer,
    fix2.[Date] AS NextOnHire,
    fix2.[FirmUntil] AS NextOffhire,
    ch2.ChartererName AS NextCharterer

From Position AS po

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Date], 
        [FirmUntil], 
        [Charterer], 
        [VesselId] FROM Fixture
    ) AS fix1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 [Date], 
        [FirmUntil], 
        [Charterer] FROM Fixture AS f2
    WHERE fix1.[VesselId] = f2.[VesselId] 
        AND f2.[Date] > fix1.[FirmUntil] 
    ORDER BY f2.[Date] ASC
    ) AS fix2

LEFT JOIN Vessel AS ve ON ve.Id = fix1.VesselId
LEFT JOIN Charterer AS ch1 ON ch1.Id = fix1.Charterer
LEFT JOIN Charterer AS ch2 ON ch2.Id = fix2.Charterer
```

Originally I thought it was perhaps the ordering of the statements but that didn't seem to change anything.  I can't see anything that's obvious and so would appreciate another set of eyes to perhaps check.

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` requires an `ON`. You're missing one for your `LEFT JOIN` to the sub query aliased as `fix1`. I *assume* that it should be an `OUTER APPLY` as well? If not, you need to add said `ON` clause after the sub query's alias declaration and prior to the following `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: So simple, I must have been staring at this for too long.  Thanks